# Select2 isn't working fine on a chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

I'm experiencing a bad behavior of Select2 on a chrome extension using **AngularJS** and Angular-UI.

### The scenario

Select2's content is loaded asynchronously via AngularJs $resouces module.

---

### What should happen?

The content should be display when i click on the Select2.

---

### What is actually happening?

When i first click on any select2 dropdown, it just winks and then hides.

---

**Obs.:**
The same code works just fine out of chrome's extension popup.
You can see it working here: http://moneynow2.apphb.com.
And can browse the code [here at my github repository](https://github.com/alanrsoares/MoneyNow2/tree/master/MoneyNow2.Chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine working fine in Chrome extension, but I'm getting "*Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*" In chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to test.

It looks like in a popup, when I open the dropmenu, the route gets reloaded (the whole controller and contents of ng-view reloads). This doesn't occur on the webpage. I thought that the popup was appearing in the bottom-right corner, stretching out the window (it happened as I stepped through it). When this occurred, I thought it might have triggered a window-scroll event which actually causes select2 to disappear (it's a feature of select2 to prevent the dropmenu from staying in some random place since it's pos:fixed).

I also don't know enough about chrome popups to figure out what events may cause the 'url' to change or a scroll event to trigger, etc.

At first I would have suggested doing selectOptions = { data: $myResource.query() } or something, but I'm starting to think it won't help.

#### Suggestion:

Try removing the router and see what happens. I don't really know that you should bother with it in a chrome extension. In such a small space, less code is probably better anyway.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try removing the router and see what happens.